# Can nhibernate be used without doing the XML mapping?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, hibernate, orm

I have a lot of classes and this is a lot of work to do the XML mappings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595637/whats-the-most-productive-way-to-do-nhibernate-mapping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, nHibernate can be used without XBM files.

There is a [fluent interface](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) for configuration and mapping, which should give you a more type safe way to map your classes.

You can use the [auto mapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping) feature and fall back to fluent mapping as needed.

Comment: you've answered two of my answers tonight. Thanks for that

Comment: "However, you still need to do the mapping." FNH has thing called auto-mapping. It is possible to avoid manual mapping. Doing that right now with huge success. http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping

Comment: @Arnis - Thanks for the tid-bit. Wasn't aware of this feature. Answer updated.

Comment: You can also use nhibernate attributes. Of course, what this does is serialize the XML files in the background in a memorystream... But it's much more convenient than writing the XML by hand.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use [Castle ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/) too. It does not require mapping hbm files.

Answer (score 0):

All mentioned technologies are creating XML under the cover. The only framework that maps entities directly without XML is [ConfORM](http://code.google.com/p/codeconform/). But you can use it only with NHibernate 3.